# MVC HTML helper wrapper for jqPlot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, html-helper, jqplot

I wish to create an MVC wrapper around jqPlot.

I want to have a helper object to render the required html container element and the required java scripts to draw the chart.

Something that will look like this:

```
@Html.jqPlot()
     .ChartType(eChartTypes.PieChart)
     .ChartData(someData)
     .RenderChart();
```

Now I'm only at the initial design phase and I know what the jqPlot object should look like to achieve that, the problem I'm having is with the java script that suppose to be emitted to draw the actual chart using jqPlot.

Suppose I will render the following script in my `.RenderChart()` method

```
public string RenderChart()
{
   string chartCode = string.format(@"
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         var plot1 = $.jqplot ('{0}', [{1}]);
      });
   ",this.ChartGuid, this.ChartData);
   return chartCode;
}
```

The above is not actual code but just a general representation of the idea.

So the problem is that i don't want the Helper to emit the JS code into the body of the Html document, furthermore i cannot let it do that becuse some of the required scripts may be at the bottom of the html (as the best practice states).

Any suggestions ? 
What would be the best way to emit JS code using an HTML helper if the situation requires it (like this one) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, listening to an even will be a possible solution, in this case the even of outputting or finishing the rendering of the footer. so maybe your code will give as an option to listen to an event and render at that moment, but this is of course platform dependent. I also worked on a php wrapper you can fork it here:  https://github.com/oumsofiane1/jqplotPHPwrapper.git
and just implemented a helper, but of course you can extend that :-)

Hope this helps